# While Scrolling Fragment toolbar should hide in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design, androiddesignsupport

I want a Toolbar + FrameLyout(Fragment)

Inside FrameLayout(TabLayout + View Pager)

I have added the code what I have tried. Please see the below code what I have tried or give some alternate idea for this scenario

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        BlankFragment  mSlidingTabsHomeFragment = new BlankFragment();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.Container, mSlidingTabsHomeFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- AppBar Layout   -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Container" >
    </FrameLayout>   

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**BlankFragment.java**

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)view. findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        if (viewPager != null) {
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 3");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
```

**fragment_blank.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is it necessary for you to have a framelayout and show viewpager in Fragment ? why can't you put the viewpager in your main layout of Activity

Comment: because I have to refactor an existing code

Comment: you have to hide the toolbar when changing the pages in viewpager or scrolling the fragment vertically?

Comment: scrolling the fragment vertically

Comment: try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to `FrameLayout` or to `LinearLayout` in `fragment_blank.xml`

Comment: Sure I will try let you know

Comment: @Deva cheeseListFragment shows list of items in ListView or RecyclerView?

Comment: It is an RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

You can call viewpager.onPageChangeListener and hide your toolbar in its onPageScrolled method.below is the syntax :-

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            //hide your toolbar here
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
               //display it again.


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
               // do nothing
            }
        });
```